# Enable requiredfield validator based on a dropdown value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a dropdown and two user controls in an .aspx page where the requiredfield validation for these two user controls is controlled by the dropdown value.

For Eg: if the dropdown value is "YES" I need to enable the Requiredfield validation for these two user controls, if drop down value is "NO", I need to disable these two fields and disable the validation control as well on these two.

I am not sure how to enable/disable the required field validator from Javascript/jquery in ASP.Net Webforms application.

Answer (score 1):

you can have two elements. one with required attribute and one without required attribute.
based on the value of your drop down append the proper element to your container.

```
if(value){
$( "#container" ).append( "<input type='text' required>" );
else $( "#container" ).append( "<input type='text'>" );
```